# Bootrec freezes - Do I need to reinstall?

Tags: boot, windows-server-2008, ntldr

Today I went to boot my server only to notice the message we all dread and fear:

> NTLDR is missing

I booted to the Server 2008 Recovery Console (or whatever its real name is), and issued this command:

> bootrec / fixmbr 
>          The operation completed successfully. 
>     bootrec /fixboot 
>          Element not found. 
>     bootrec /scanos 
>          Scanning all disks for Windows installations. 
>  
>          Please wait, since this may take a while...

I've been please-waiting for about two hours now in preparation to run /rebuildbcd (Which I tried before and also gave up after 3 hours).  Do I need to reinstall my OS?

This is a fresh install of Server 2008 on a brand-new [Velociraptor](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136296&cm_re=velociraptor-_-22-136-296-_-Product).

*Note I didn't put this on Serverfault because it's a personal system, not enterprisey stuff.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix. It wasn't frozen, just had to wait several hours, possibly related to there being 10 physical disks on two distinct controllers. Was able to fix with a few bootrec and diskpart commands.

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of disks for a home system.  If this happens again it might be worth disconnecting the disks that don't have the os on while doing the scan.

Comment: Yeah there was a bad drive, I found and unplugged it.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound slightly trashed, you could try booting from an ubuntu liveCD and running testdisk to see if it can find your partition table and recover it.