# Vista/Server 2008: BOOTMGR is missing

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-server-2008, bootloader

My NTLDR [recently went missing](https://superuser.com/questions/46625/bootrec-freezes-do-i-need-to-reinstall), and I was able to fix that. However, now my BOOTMGR is also missing, and I have tried all the solutions on the whole Internet to fix it. Below are the actions I've taken in the recovery command prompt:

- bootrec /fixmbr

  - The operation completed successfully.
- bootrec /fixboot

  - Element not found.
- bootrec /rebuildbcd

  - > Successfully scanned Windows installations. 
    > Total identified Windows installations: 1 
    > [1]  C:\Windows 
    > Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):y 
    > Element not found.
- diskpart  
  list disk
  select disk 4 
  select partition 1 
  active

  - DiskPart marked the current partition as active.
- bootrec /rebuildbcd

  - > Successfully scanned Windows installations. 
    > Total identified Windows installations: 1 
    > [1]  C:\Windows 
    > Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):y 
    > The operation completed successfully.
- bootrec /fixboot

  - The operation completed successfully.
- bcdedit /export c:\boot2
  ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
  bootrec /rebuildbcd

  - > Successfully scanned Windows installations. 
    > Total identified Windows installations: 1 
    > [1]  C:\Windows 
    > Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):y 
    > The operation completed successfully.

So how do I restore my BOOTMGR without having to reinstall?

Note this question required some... *interesting* formatting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to install Windows Server 2008 on another drive, which built a new bootloader. I updated my boot loader to select the old one only and wiped the new install so as to remain in adherence to the license.

Comment: Woah, I let my domain expire and forgot to look for backlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional comment in hopes I can help the next person trying to deal with boot issues... especially after an update.

The screenshot that Will put up there is from a Vista install disc. The Windows 2008 repair options did NOT include the "Startup Repair" option (oddly enough). So, on a whim, I decided to try a Vista install disc and, sure enough, the option was there and once I selected that option - my Windows Server 2008 server FINALLY booted again.

I have no idea why MS decided to include the option on Vista discs but not 2008 discs, but this is something worth trying if you are pulling your hair out like I was. All my attempts to do command line restores were useless... I would have never imagined that a Vista install CD would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the disk (either Windows Vista or 2008) in and click repair, it should be able to scan for common startup problems. One of them will check for the Boot Manager files and active partitions e.t.c.

It should be able to get you going quickly. If the automatic scanner doesn't work, you may have to click on the "Startup Repair" option.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option. I have CompletePC Restore (or something like it, it mentions images), Memory Diagnostic Tool, and Command Prompt.  Also note that it only detects my install some of the time when I go in here.

Comment: If you have Technet or MSDN, or any ISO of Windows Vista / 7, try using that and doing the Startup Repair, it should be cross version and work on any.

Comment: Edit: The one I couldn't remember is "Windows Complete PC Restore".  Strange mine has a space and yours doesn't.